# EF Audit Trail with ChangeTracker - detect change in Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement Audit Trail by overriding SaveChangeAsync method. With ChangeTracker.Entries() I am able to get list of all the properties that are being modified or added. This works with normal entity without any FK. But with FK, if I assigned foreign entity via navigation property, ChangeTracker is not detecting change in relevant FK.

let's say I have these classes

```
class Parent{
  int ParentID,
  string Name,
}

class Child {
  int ChildID,
  int GenderID,
  string Name

  virtual Gender Gender{get;set;}
}

class ParentChild {
   int ParentChildID,
   int ParentID,
   int ChildID,
   string RelationName;

  virtual Parent Parent {get;set;}
  virtual Child Child {get;set;}
}
```

Inserting new Record

```
Var p = new Parent{ Name="p1"};
var c = new Child {Name ="c1"};

context.ParentChild.Add(new ParentChild {
  Parent = p,
  Child = c,
  RelationName = "First child"
};

context.SaveChangeAsync();
```

Issue here is because I am assigning Parent and Child in ParentChild entity via navigation property, ChangeTracker doesn't detect any change in ParentID & ChildID in ParentChild entity but DB does updates both FK.

This is how I am logging changes

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(p => p.State != EntityState.Unchanged && p.State != EntityState.Detached).ToList();
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            List<AuditTemp> changes = new List<AuditTemp>();
            foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
            {
                var entityName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
                var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(change) ?? 0;

                foreach (var prop in change.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
                {
                    string originalValue = "";
                    string currentValue = "";
                    currentValue = (change.CurrentValues[prop]??"").ToString();
                    if (change.State == EntityState.Modified)
                        originalValue = (change.OriginalValues[prop]??"").ToString();

                    if (originalValue != currentValue)
                    {
                        AuditTemp log = new AuditTemp()
                        {
                            Entity = change,
                            Audit = new Audit()
                            {
                                TableName = entityName,

                                FieldName = prop,
                                OldValue = originalValue,
                                NewValue = currentValue,
                                UpdateDate = now
                            }
                        };
                        changes.Add(log);
                    }
                }

            }
             int a =  await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            foreach (var c in changes)
            {
                c.Audit.NewValue = c.Entity.CurrentValues[c.Audit.FieldName].ToString();
                c.Audit.RecordID = Convert.ToInt64(GetPrimaryKeyValue(c.Entity)??0);
                this.Audits.Add(c.Audit);
            }

            await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            return a;
        }
```

I am updating/adding log after calling SaveChanges to get auto generated key for Insert.

I shave any way to detect change in FK (updated via navigation property) and log them.

Many Thanks

Comment: But at this point ParentID and ChildID are not yet known (as I understand - that are autogenerated ids in your case), so what exactly you want to log?

Comment: yes, they are not known/generated yet but after calling saveChanges() ef generates key and assigns it to appropriate FK in ParentChild table. So FK in ParentChild table changes from 0 to N.

Comment: Yes I see I missed that you set values also after SaveChanges.